# Java stream - Cannot modify the contents of a list with forEach

Tags: java, arraylist, functional-programming, java-stream

I have to implement a method `map()` below which receives an array list and a `Function<T, R>` object, and
returns an array list consisting of the results of applying the function to the given elements.

The following code prints `1,2,3` instead of squares of those numbers. Why does the code not work? I need the reason for failure and not correct solutions.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.function.Function;
import java.util.stream.Collectors;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Mapper {
    public static ArrayList<Integer> map(ArrayList<Integer> nums, Function<Integer, Integer> mapper) {
        ArrayList<Integer> result = new ArrayList<>(nums);
        result.forEach(e -> e = mapper.apply(e));
        return result;
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<Integer> nums = IntStream.rangeClosed(1, 3).boxed().collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
        ArrayList<Integer> squares = Mapper.map(nums, z -> z * z);
        squares.forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because in `result.forEach(e -> ... )` `e` is not a reference to the list element, but a value of integer from the list. Think of that line as equivalent to this:

```
for (int e : nums) {
  e = e * e;
}
```

This would not update elements in the `num` collection either.

Answer (score 0):

In your case `map` would be more appropriate:

```
public static ArrayList<Integer> map(ArrayList<Integer> nums, Function<Integer, Integer> mapper) {
    return nums.stream()
        .map(mapper)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because in `result.forEach(e -> ... )` where "e" is not a reference an element, instead it's a reference to the value.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.lang.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.function.*;
import java.util.stream.*;

public class Mapper {
    public static List<Integer> map(List<Integer> numbers, Function<Integer, Integer> mapper) {
        return numbers.stream()
            .map(mapper)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static void main(String [] args){
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>(Arrays. asList(1, 2));
        map(numbers, number -> number * number).forEach(System.out::println);
    }
}
```